# Seeing 500 error page but no errors can be find in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My ruby app starts successfully but when I go to localhost:3000 I see this page:

[image]

Checking the production.log file it only has one line:

```
# Logfile created on Tue Oct 28 10:47:41 -0500 2014luser@luser-VirtualBox:~/Repo/adm$
```

Mongrel.log indicates the app started successfully:

```
** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at log/mongrel.pid and log/mongrel.log for info.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 127.0.0.1:3000
** Starting Rails with production environment...
/home/luser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning:    Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
** Rails loaded.
** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins
** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.
** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at 127.0.0.1:3000
** Writing PID file to log/mongrel.pid
```

How do I go about resolving this problem?

Comment: Do you run in production or development mode? The error page suggests production mode, but the url suggests development mode. Check `development.log` to see if it contains useful information.

Comment: The log actually says `Starting Rails with production environment...`, so I think it's safe to assume that's the case. What gave you the idea that it would be development?

Comment: I tried to run the app in both mode. In either case, production.log/development.log shows the same one liner about logfile creation but nothing else.

Comment: @Frost Ah, missed that one. :)

Comment: Did you define the root_path in `config/routes`?

Comment: I needed to specify log level in config/environment/development.rb. config.log_level = :debug